# Create multiple properties with the same getters and setters

Tags: javascript, setter, getter, getter-setter

Recently I've been writing some JavaScript program which involves the use of [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). I read the MDN documentation for both methods, but I got confused trying to use them.

I want to create a series of similar properties, which will have the same getters and setters, but *I don't want to rewrite every single setter and getter* for every property.

### Implementation

Stated the above, I tried executing the following code:

```
var defaultProperty = {
    set: function(val) {
        this.value = val - 1; // Just an example
    },
        
    get: function() {
        return this.value + 1; // Just an example
    }
};

var myObj = {};
Object.defineProperties(myObj, {
    foo: defaultProperty,
    bar: defaultProperty
});
```

Then I assigned new values to my `foo` and `bar` properties, like this:

```
myObj.foo = 3;
myObj.bar = 7;
```

And, finally, I was expecting something like this:

```
console.log(myObj.foo, myObj.bar);
> 3 7
```

But I unexpectedly got this instead:

```
> 7 7
```

It looks like the two properties are either referring to the same memory address or sharing the same setters/getters. Noticed this, I tried to solve the problem, and created each property separately, like this:

```
Object.defineProperties(myObj, {
    foo: {
        set: function(val) {
            this.value = val - 1;
        },
        
        get: function() {
            return this.value + 1;
        }
    },

    bar: {
        set: function(val) {
            this.value = val - 1;
        },
        
        get: function() {
            return this.value + 1;
        }
    }
});
```

But the result was the same:

```
myObj.foo = 3;
myObj.bar = 7;
console.log(myObj.foo, myObj.bar);
> 7 7
```

I also tried using the `__defineSetter__` and `__defineGetter__` functions, but the result didn't change.

### My questions

Now, after several failed attempts to solve my problems, I'm wondering:

- Is it possible to define the same setters and getters on different properties of an object?
- If so, what am I doing wrong, and **why do my properties behave like they're the same property?**
- Is there any better method to accomplish what I'm trying to do (possibly without writing each setter and getter for every property)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to define the same setters and getters on different properties of an object?

Yes, although it's not recommended as you can see from your experience.

> what am I doing wrong, and why do my properties behave like they're the same property?

Because they store/access the value that was set/gotten is always stored in the same `.value` property on your object: `myObj.value == 6` so both `myObj.foo` and `myObj.bar` yield `7`.

> Is there any better method to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Store the values in closure scope variables, and use a function to define the properties:

```
function makeDefaultProperty(obj, name) {
    var value;
    return Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
        set: function(val) {
            value = val - 1; // Just an example
        },
        get: function() {
            return value + 1; // Just an example
        }
    });
};

var myObj = {};
makeDefaultProperty(myObj, "foo");
makeDefaultProperty(myObj, "bar");
```

Of course, instead of the local variable you simply might use distinct "internal" properties, and you might also use a different way of creating the common setters/getters by a function. Both applied:

```
function defaultProperty(name) {
    return {
        set: function(val) {
            this[name] = val - 1; // Just an example
        },
        get: function() {
            return this[name] + 1; // Just an example
        }
    };
}

var myObj = Object.defineProperties({}, {
    foo: defaultProperty("_foo"),
    bar: defaultProperty("_bar")
});
```

Comment: Well thanks for the detailed and diversified answer, I actually really like the closure method!

Comment: @Thefoureye: Thanks for your edit. I'd given your answer an upvote for the use of `bind` if you had not deleted it :-/

Comment: Just to pick a nit, the op was binding `value` to `this` which is what was causing the unexpected result. The scope for `this` had not changed. Using your generator function breaks the scope creating separate references for the `value`.